# windows cmd to copy the text between two points in a .sql file and write to another .sql File

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line, git-bash

There is this mySQL dump file(file.sql) with the table structures and insert statements for a database.

```
--DO NOT COPY
--DO NOT COPY
-- Table structure for table `address`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `address`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `address` (
`ENCODEDKEY` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`ADDRESSTYPE` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 
NULL,
`CITY` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `address`
--

 LOCK TABLES `address` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `address` VALUES ( 'ENCODEDKEY','ADDRESSTYPE','CITY');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
--DO NOT COPY
--DO NOT COPY
```

I want to copy the text from this file.sql between two points which is a starting point to a ending point.

The starting point should be the exact string of =

> Table structure for table 'find_tablename'

The ending point should be exact string of =

> UNLOCK TABLES;

And I want to copy/read all the text between those 2 points and write to a new .sql file

This Unix command using SED does the task:

```
sed -n -e '/-- Table structure for table `address`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' file.sql > new_file.sql
```

However i am looking for the windows equivalent using the command line(cmd). I started to do this with the @type command but I need some sort of IF statement to tell the process to only copy all the text between those 2 points and write to a new .sql file.

```
@type C:\Users\Documents\file.sql > C:\Users\Documents\new_file.sql
```

Comment: why not have a ubuntu vm  and do it there?

Comment: @nbk Powershell performed the operation in a fraction of the time in comparison to the SED command. I accepted the answer which was provided by Marzse below. It does the job with greater performance.

Comment: i know that powershel can do it, but if you have a vm and can handle sed you will find many uses for that vm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a command for this specific case. And I hope you're not going to try this in cmd.exe.

In PowerShell, you could do this:

```
$write = $false
$(switch -CaseSensitive -File ("file.sql") {
    '-- Table structure for table `address`' { $write = $true; $_ }
    'UNLOCK TABLES;' { if ($write) { $_; break; } }
    default { if ($write) { $_ }}
}) | Set-Content "new_file.sql"
```

If you need something like this more often, you could write your own function for it.

Comment: Nice one! Glad to see you more active again lately.

Comment: @marsze I just tried your code with my original mysql dump file and it only writes "UNLOCK TABLES;" to a new .sql file when I put the name of a table I want. The original mySQL dump file contains the structures for up to 200 tables where 'address' was one of them. The strange thing is that it works on the example above how it is in my question

Comment: @marsze ok, I just executed with your update. It's running now so I guess it's searching through that huge file, but before it would have ran in a second. I will update as soon as it finished if it does writes to the .sql with the expected output. It would have take a long time also to execute with the SED command on on unix.

Comment: @marsze Thanks Bro! it works now. The Powershell does the process way faster with great performance. The SED command would take like 2-3 hours to get it done. This script in Powershell took 10 mins to do the same process. I could also see greater performance with the process via the Task Manager.

Comment: @marsze Yes seems I need to learn some PowerShell Scripting. This will help me out greatly. I might ask a next question cause there is something else I want to do which would require a Loop to automate the process fully. In this case it was 1 table (address) but what if I wanted to do the same process for like 10 different tables and it writes to just one .sql file.

Comment: @JasonX Powershell makes every developer's life easier ;) That's also why I take my time to answer questions here.

Comment: @marsze Hey, I added new question located at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748232/powershell-command-to-read-between-two-points-in-a-loop-and-write-to-end-of-file

Answer (score 2):

You could also use regex in powershell for similar result

```
$pattern = '(?s)(-- Table structure.+UNLOCK TABLES;\r?\n)'

$rawcontent = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Documents\file.sql -Raw

if($rawcontent -match $pattern){
    Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Documents\new_file.sql -Value $matches.1
}
```

Note the `-Raw` option on `Get-Content` is required to gather all contents as a single string. `(?s)` is a regex modifier to indicate single string.

I broke the commands apart for readability, you can also compress into

```
if((Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Documents\file.sql -Raw) -match '(?s)(-- Table structure.+UNLOCK TABLES;\r?\n)'){
    Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Documents\new_file.sql -Value $matches.1
}
```

or

```
Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Documents\new_file.sql -Value $(if((Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Documents\file.sql -Raw) -match '(?s)(-- Table structure.+UNLOCK TABLES;\r?\n)'){$matches.1})
```

or even

```
Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Documents\new_file.sql -Value (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Documents\file.sql -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?s)(-- Table structure.+UNLOCK TABLES;\r?\n)').matches.value
```

Answer (score 0):

If sed cuts it

then try a windows port of sed from https://github.com/mbuilov/sed-windows

one file 300-400 KB 32bit or 64bit (no guarantees but seems to work in this case) e.g.

```
curl -o sed.exe https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbuilov/sed-windows/master/sed-4.8-x64.exe
```

syntax on windows needs "double quote"

```
sed.exe -n -e "/-- Table structure for table `address`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p" test.sql > new_file.sql
```

```
-- Table structure for table `address`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `address`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `address` (
`ENCODEDKEY` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`ADDRESSTYPE` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT
NULL,
`CITY` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `address`
--

 LOCK TABLES `address` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `address` VALUES ( 'ENCODEDKEY','ADDRESSTYPE','CITY');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

[image]