# Powershell command to read between two points in a Loop and write to end of file

Tags: powershell

There is this mySQL file (file.sql) and I want to copy the text between two points which is a starting and a ending point and write to a new .sql file. I need this in a Loop which will run for N number of tables in a Array and write to a new .sql file. At the end of each iteration, I need the process to add new line then append the text of new table to the end of the file.

```
--DO NOT COPY
--DO NOT COPY
-- Table structure for table `address`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `address`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `address` (
`ENCODEDKEY` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`ADDRESSTYPE` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 
NULL,
`CITY` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `address`
--

 LOCK TABLES `address` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `address` VALUES ( 'ENCODEDKEY','ADDRESSTYPE','CITY');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
--DO NOT COPY
--DO NOT COPY
 
-- Table structure for table `client`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `client`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `client` (
`KEY` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`TYPE` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `client`
--

 LOCK TABLES `client` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `client` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `client` VALUES ( 'KEY','TYPE');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
--DO NOT COPY
--DO NOT COPY
```

For Each Iteration, the starting point should be the exact string of =

> Table structure for table 'find_tablename'

The ending point should be exact string of =

> UNLOCK TABLES;

And I want to copy/read all the text between those 2 points and write to a new .sql file. This process should be in a Loop and the Loop would run for N number of tables and appending to the same .sql file after adding new line. In this case it would run for 2 iterations that is for the tables address and client.

There is this script which executes the process in PowerShell for the address table. I also was thinking to use Array as seen below in the comments which allows me to easily add/remove tables I need then use a FOR LOOP for iteration. The code I have in comments is what I was trying to add to execute this Loop. So the value as position tableList[num] would subsititue `address` .

```
 # $tableList = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList';
 # $tableList.Add("address")
 # $tableList.Add("client")

 # for ($num = 1 ; $num -le $tableList.Count ; $num++)
 # {
$write = $false
$(switch -CaseSensitive -File ("file.sql") {
'-- Table structure for table `address`' { $write = $true; $_ }
'UNLOCK TABLES;' { if ($write) { $_; break; } }
default { if ($write) { $_ }}
 }) | Set-Content "new_file.sql"
 #}
```

Comment: Is it really a fixed array of tables, or do you want to extract *all* tables? You should remove the `break` and instead reset `$write`. Also, you can use string expansion in your switch : `"-- Table structure for table $tableName"`

Comment: Yes, a fixed array of tables. So the file has structures for over 200 tables where client and address are 2 of them.  Let's say I want to extract the structures for 10 of these table, then I would add the names of these tables I need  to the array list and the Loop should run for 10 times to allow the process to write to the same .sql file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the existing solution, I created this function:

```
function Select-TableSql {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
        [string[]]$TableNames
    )
    $write = $false
    switch -Regex -File ($Path) {
        '-- Table structure for table `(?<TableName>\w+)`' {
            if ($Matches.TableName -in $TableNames) {
                $write = $true
                $_
            }
        }
        'UNLOCK TABLES;' {
            if ($write) {
                $write = $false
                $_
            }
        }
        default {
            if ($write) {
                $_
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Select-TableSql file.sql client, address | Set-Content new_file.sql
```

(*Note: The purpose of using `switch` here on a file directly is because it's much faster on large files than any combination with `Get-Content`.*)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `switch` on this, but a combination of `-split`, `-replace` and finally `-join`:

```
# read the original file as single multiline string
$sql = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\SqlFile.sql' -Raw

# 1) split the whole content on 'UNLOCK TABLES'
# 2) keep only the text blocks that contain '-- Table structure for table'
# 3) remove all text above '-- Table structure for table' from each text block. 
# 4) Append the final 'UNLOCK TABLES;' sql command we've removed using the first split

$result = $sql -split '(?ms)^UNLOCK TABLES;\s\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -match '-- Table structure for table' } | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -replace '(?ms)^.*(-- Table structure for table .*)', '$1') + "UNLOCK TABLES;"
}
```

You can now save the resulting array as individual files, but if I understand the question correctly, you want to merge the array into one new file

```
$result -join "`r`n`r`n" | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\newSqlFile.sql'
```

The resulting file will look like this:

```
-- Table structure for table `address`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `address`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `address` (
`ENCODEDKEY` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`ADDRESSTYPE` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 
NULL,
`CITY` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `address`
--

 LOCK TABLES `address` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `address` VALUES ( 'ENCODEDKEY','ADDRESSTYPE','CITY');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

-- Table structure for table `client`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `client`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `client` (
`KEY` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`TYPE` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `client`
--

 LOCK TABLES `client` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `client` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `client` VALUES ( 'KEY','TYPE');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `address` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

---

**Edit**

Indeed I didn't read anything in your question about filtering out only a fixed set of tables, but that is quite easy to implement:

```
# the list of table names you want to retrieve from the file
$tablesToExtract = 'address','client','someothertable' # etc.

# read the original file as single multiline string
$sql = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\SqlFile.sql' -Raw

# 1) split the whole content on 'UNLOCK TABLES'
# 2) keep only the text blocks that contain '-- Table structure for table'
# 3) parse out the table name and check if that can be found in the $tablesToExtract array
# 4) remove all text above '-- Table structure for table' from each text block. 
# 5) Append the final 'UNLOCK TABLES;' sql command we've removed using the first split
$result = $sql -split '(?ms)^UNLOCK TABLES;\s\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -match '-- Table structure for table' } | ForEach-Object {
    # check if the table is in the list
    $tableName = ([regex]'-- Table structure for table `(\w+)`').Match($_).Groups[1].Value
    if ($tablesToExtract -contains $tableName) {
        ($_ -replace '(?ms)^.*(-- Table structure for table .*)', '$1') + "UNLOCK TABLES;"
    }
}
```

You can now save the resulting array as individual files, but if I understand the question correctly, you want to merge the array into one new file

```
$result -join "`r`n`r`n" | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\newSqlFile.sql'
```

Comment: you seem to miss the part of question where I need like a Array to store fixed number of table names I want to extract.  This array would be passed to -- Table structure for table arraylist[tablename]. Your solution would have worked if I wanted to extract all tables but I really want to extract only fixed number of tables from the huge .sql file which contains over 200 tables.

Comment: @JasonX Yes, indeed.. I have re-read your question but still couldn't find that requirement in there.. Anyway, Please see my edit where the code now only retrieves tables that are named in your fixed string array.